# Serial.print query

Tags: arduino-uno

is it even possible to print a variable output with 4 digits before and one digit after decimal in serial monitor?

my pot reading is shown in the above output

```
value   -   1.2
value   -   51.5
value   -   61.8
value   -   546.6
value   -   255.0
value   -   1235.9
```

to this

```
value   -   0001.2
value   -   0051.5
value   -   0061.8
value   -   0546.6
value   -   0255.0
value   -   1235.9
```

Comment: There are some implementations of printf() kicking around in some libraries.  If they are fully implemented you could use the command `printf ("value   -  %04.1f\n", value);` and that will give you 4 digits before the DP padded with zeros and one after the DP.

Comment: stdio sprintf and co. are build in, but without %f support. simplest is to code print of necessary count of zeros

Comment: `%f` specified does *not* work with Arduino provided functions like `snprintf`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, those are AVR libraries, not Arduino. http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html

Comment: @Juraj Sorry I misread the comment. I somehow read that they *are* supported, not that they are not. my mistake.

Comment: While the libraries are not Arduino, the decision to link the full or miniature one not supporting floating point *is* an Arduino one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basiscally want a format string which includes `%f`. However on Arduino, that only returns a `?` (not included to to space reasons). Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/27651012/5296568.

However the alternative is `dtostrf` ([double-to-string-formatted](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42.html)). The function takes the `double` / `float` value, the total wanted width of the string and the decimal places you want to have.

However it fills the string with spaces to the left until the total width is met. You need an additional pass to replace it with `0`.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    const float vals[] = {
            1.2, 51.5, 61.8,
            546.6, 255.0,
            1235.9
    };

    //allocate 8 byte buffer
    //biggest string is "-9999.9\0" (with NUL)
    char buf[8];

    int numVals = (int) (sizeof(vals) / sizeof(*vals));

    for(int i=0; i < numVals; i++) {
        //format correctly
        dtostrf(vals[i], 4+1+1, 1, buf);

        //convert left-appended spaces to zeroes
        for(size_t j=0; j < sizeof(buf); j++){
            if(buf[j] == ' ')
                buf[j] = '0';
        }

        //print buffer
        Serial.println(buf);
    }
}


void loop() {
}
```

Prints

```
0001.2
0051.5
0061.8
0546.6
0255.0
1235.9
```

Edit: You can also offload it into a function and then feed it with the ADC values.

Example:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

void printValueFormatted(float value, int numDecimalPlaces, int totalWidth) {
    //format correctly
    char buf[16]; 
    //prevent buffer overflow
    if(totalWidth >= (int) sizeof(buf))
         return;
    dtostrf(value, totalWidth, numDecimalPlaces, buf);

    //convert left-appended spaces to zeroes
    for(size_t j=0; j < sizeof(buf); j++){
        if(buf[j] == ' ')
            buf[j] = '0';
    }

    //print buffer without newline
    Serial.print(buf);
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
}


void loop() {
    float val = analogRead(0);
    Serial.print("ADC Count: ");
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.print("  -- Voltage: ");
    val = val * 5.0f / 1023.0f;
    printValueFormatted(val, 1, 4+1+1);
    //print newline
    Serial.println();
    delay(100);
}
```

Prints

```
ADC Count: 719.00  -- Voltage: 0003.5
ADC Count: 718.00  -- Voltage: 0003.5
```

Comment: What if i want to change the input analog value to this type of format! then what should I do?

Comment: @PeouseDutta I updated the code a bit, do you understand now?

Comment: Yes that was very helpful. :)

Comment: Why it is not working when I am printing it on a LCD?

it is showing 13.800 instead of 0013.8

Comment: @PeouseDutta Can you pastebin the code you're running?

Comment: i posted the entire code have a look

Comment: @PeouseDutta OK since this is quite lengthy I think it might be best if you asked this as an new question and delete your 'answer' here (because it is not an answer). Also include what it prints in the serial console there.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(val < 1000){Serial.print('0');}
if(val < 100){Serial.print('0');}
if(val < 10){Serial.print('0');}
Serial.println(val, 1);
```

Comment: This is going to fail for values just under powers of 10.  Consider `999.99` - that is indeed less than 1000, so a leading zero gets printed, but the value itself rounds to `1000.0` when limited to one digit after the decimal point.  You end up with `01000.0`, one character too many.  (The idea would work just fine with integer values.)

Comment: As is, this isn't going to work. However, it does suggest a strategy of pre-converting to an integer type and a fraction, being careful to get those correctly rounded, and then printing them in an individually formatted manner.